# How can I prevent Android from auto locking while activity (application) is in focus?

Tags: android, locking

I'm new to android development. How can I prevent Android from locking while my application is in focus? When my application is out of focus I want to ensure than the android os will have its default behavior.

Answer (score 9):

use

> WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON

you can do this using

> Activity.getWindow().addFlags().

Answer (score 0):

```
private PowerManager mPowerManager;
private WakeLock mWakeLock;

Write this in OnCreate 

 // Get an instance of the PowerManager
    mPowerManager = (PowerManager) getSystemService(POWER_SERVICE);

    // Create a bright wake lock
    mWakeLock = mPowerManager.newWakeLock(PowerManager.SCREEN_BRIGHT_WAKE_LOCK|
            PowerManager.ACQUIRE_CAUSES_WAKEUP, getClass()
            .getName());

Write this in onResume

    mWakeLock.acquire();


write this in onPause

    mWakeLock.release();
```

Comment: Please DO NOT do this.  There is no need.  This just requires that your app have the user grant it permission to the power manager, and gives you more opportunity for bugs where you leave the screen on.  The correct answer is the one using FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON.

Comment: by the way in following the above procedure the phone is remain unlock as long as the phone screeen is portriat or landscape but when we change the orientation when the autolock period is expired then the phone get locked automaticallly